# What happens to session value after it expires?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-timeout

I just want to know what will happen to the `session` after it reach it timeout.

I went through the question about “[What happens to cart object when session expires?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261542/what-happens-to-cart-object-when-session-expires)” but it doesn’t explain much.

Does it completely remove the `session` object or making it `null`?

Thanks

Comment: @leppie: I believe on Windows Servers it would be RecycleBin :) but dev/null is a classic deadend anyway

Comment: @leppie, oh no! I believe all session variables go to Heaven

Comment: @sll: on Windows it would be `NUL` Eg: `echo 1 >> NUL`

Comment: Don't listen to them @Yuriy! - they *do* go to session heaven

Comment: Isn't there a stack exchange site for such existential questions? What happens to any of us when we reach our timeout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the session timeout occurs the `Session_End` event in `global.asax` is raised (except when session is handled by the DB) and the session collection is cleared. (the items are removed) If no other object is holding a reference to a particular object in the session collection the  GC will collect it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, only the session state will be removed. i.e.  all items that had been stored in the Session will be discarded. However, it depends upon the session-state modes ([MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx)). In some cases the session object might be null ([read SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1382811/142822)).